# Half Angle Trig and Complex Numbers

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

By making use of the half-angle formulae, or otherwise, prove that 
$$\frac{1+\cos x+i\sin x}{1-\cos x+i\sin x}=\cot{\frac x2} e^{i(x-\frac\pi2)}$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1+\cos2y+i\sin2y}{1-\cos2y+i\sin2y}=\frac{2\cos^2y+2i\sin y\cos y}{2\sin^2y+2i\sin y\cos y}$$

$$=\frac{\cos y(\cos y+i\sin y)}{\sin y(\sin y+i\cos y)}$$

$$=\cot y\frac{\cos y+i\sin y}{\cos\left(\frac\pi2-y\right)+i\sin \left(\frac\pi2-y\right)}$$

$$=\cot y\frac{e^{iy}}{e^{i\left(\frac\pi2-y\right)}}$$

using Euler's Identity $:\cos z+i\sin z=e^{iz}$